# optimizing a line of C code for 8 bit processor

Tags: c, optimization, multiplication, addition

I'm working on a 8bit processor and have written code in a C compiler, now more than 140 lines of code are taking just 1200 bytes and this single line is taking more than 200 bytes of ROM space. `eeprom_read()` is a function, there should be a problem with this 1000 and 100 and 10 multiplication.

```
romAddr = eeprom_read(146)*1000 + eeprom_read(147)*100 +
          eeprom_read(148)*10 + eeprom_read(149);
```

Processor is 8-bit and data type of `romAddr` is `int`. Is there any way to write this line in a more optimized way?

Comment: What are you using to compile this?  Your compiler might support an optimize-for-space optimization, which would prevent the (possible) inline expansion of the eeprom_read function call in this statement.

Comment: Which chip is this ? Can your compiler produce the ASM code for you to read ? Can you show that to us ?

Comment: easiest way is `/Os`. Otherwise sh1's way is quite good

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the thing that uses the most space is the use of multiplication. If your processor lacks an instruction to do multiplication, the compiler is forced to use software to do it step by step, which can require quite a bit of code.

It's hard to say, since you don't specify anything about your target processor (or which compiler you're using).

One way might be to somehow try to *reduce* inlining, so the code to multiply by 10 (which is used in all four terms) can be re-used.

To know if this is the case at all, the machine code must be inspected. By the way, the use of decimal constants for an address calculation is really odd.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the multiplication can be compiled into a sequence of additions, yes. You can optimize it say by using left shift operator.

```
A*1000 = A*512 + A*256 + A*128 + A*64 + A*32 + A*8
```

Or the same thing:

```
A<<9 + A<<8 + A<<7 + A<<6 + A<<5 + A<<3
```

This still is way longer then a single "multiply" instruction, but your processor apparently doesn't have it anyway, so this might be the next best thing.

Comment: Or this: `(A << 10) - (A << 5) + (A << 3)`

Comment: Yes indeed. Your representation is better.

Comment: This works too: `((x << 7) - (x + (x << 1))) << 3` and actually the one from your post would probably work better than either of the ones I gave, OP doesn't say which cpu but most 8bit cpu's don't have a fast shift by more than 1.

Comment: @harold `(A << 10) - …` only works if `(A << 10)` does not overflow. It is fine for the programmer to use this expression when s/he knows it generates better code for his/her environment, but the compiler can only use it in substitution to `A*1000` if it was able to infer that `A` was in the range where this works.

Comment: @PascalCuoq it still works if it overflows, as long as it doesn't trap or something. The subtract will either overflow as well (fixing the problem), or not (then the multiply would have overflowed as well)

Comment: beware: + and - have [**higher precedence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than << and >>, so `A<<9 + A<<8 + A<<7 + A<<6 + A<<5 + A<<3` means `A<<(9 + A)<<(8 + A)<<(7 + A)<<(6 + A)<<(5 + A)<<3` which isn't what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You're concerned about space, not time, right?
You've got four function calls, with an integer argument being passed to each one, followed by a multiplication by a constant, followed by adding.
Just as a first guess, that could be

1. load integer constant into register (6 bytes)
2. push register (2 bytes,
3. call `eeprom_read` (6 bytes)
4. adjust stack (4 bytes)
5. load integer multiplier into register (6 bytes)
6. push both registers (4 bytes),
7. call multiplication routine (6 bytes)
8. adjust stack (4 bytes)
9. load temporary sum into a register (6 bytes)
10. add to that register the result of the multiplication (2 bytes)
11. store back in the temporary sum (6 bytes).

Let's see, 6+2+6+4+6+4+6+4+6+2+6= about 52 bytes per call to `eeprom_read`.
The last call would be shorter because it doesn't do the multiply.

I would try calling `eeprom_read` not with arguments like `146` but with `(unsigned char)146`, and multiplying not by `1000` but by `(unsigned short)1000`.
That way, you might be able to tease the compiler into using shorter instructions, and possibly using a multiply instruction rather than a multiply function call.
Also, the call to `eeprom_read` might be macro'ed into a direct memory fetch, saving the pushing of the argument, the calling of the function, and the stack adjustment.

Another trick could be to store each one of the four products in a local variable, and add them all together at the end. That could generate less code.
All these possibilities would also make it faster, as well as smaller, though you probably don't need to care about that.

Another possibility for saving space could be to use a loop, like this:

```
static unsigned short powerOf10[] = {1000, 100, 10, 1};
unsigned short i;
romAddr = 0;
for (i = 146; i < 150; i++){
  romAddr += powerOf10[i-146] * eeprom_read(i);
}
```

which should save space by having the call and the multiply only once, plus the looping instructions, rather than four copies.

In any case, get handy with the assembler language that the compiler generates.

Answer (score 1):

It depends very, very much on the compiler, but I would suggest that you at least simplify the multiplication this way:

```
romAddr = ((eeprom_read(146)*10 + eeprom_read(147))*10 +
          eeprom_read(148))*10 + eeprom_read(149);
```

You could put this in a loop:

```
uint8_t i = 146;
romAddr = eeprom_read(i);
for (i = 147; i < 150; i++)
    romAddr = romAddr * 10 + eeprom_read(i);
```

Hopefully the compiler should recognise how much simpler it is to multiply a 16-bit value by ten, compared with separately implementing multiplications by 1000 and 100.

I'm not completely comfortable relying on the compiler to deal with the loop effectively, though.

Maybe:

```
uint8_t hi, lo;
hi = (uint8_t)eeprom_read(146) * (uint8_t)10 + (uint8_t)eeprom_read(147);
lo = (uint8_t)eeprom_read(148) * (uint8_t)10 + (uint8_t)eeprom_read(149);
romAddr = hi * (uint8_t)100 + lo;
```

All of these are untested.

Comment: this way only multiplications by 10 is required and that reduces code size a lot. But the cast in `(uint8_t)10` is unnecessary because in expressions types smaller than int is always promoted to int

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I've seen 8-bit compilers which need that hint to make efficient code; but it was a few years ago.  I don't know if they're still like that.